# Swift need closure for audioplayer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, closures

I am building an app with several view controllers. I need to control music from all of them so I have created a dedicated music class which I use to setup / play / stop / pause.

I have recorded audio questions and answers and I need to be able to play the **question** and then the **answer** mp3 files.

So I believe that here a few way to accomplish this delegate and protocols, using the func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying and using closures. From what I can understand closures are the best option for what I am trying to achieve.

My starting point in the MakeMusic Class is:

```
class MakeMusicClass : NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    static let shared = MakeMusicClass()
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override init() { }

    func setup(Selection: String) {
        do {
            audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: Selection, ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.delegate=self
        } catch {
            print (error)
        }
    }

    func play() {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
```

My calling file is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MakeMusicClass.shared.setup(Selection: "Question11")
        MakeMusicClass.shared.play()

        MakeMusicClass.shared.setup(Selection: "Answer11")
        MakeMusicClass.shared.play()
```

To get this working I understand that I need to add a closure to the called class:

```
func play() {
    var closure = { in
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

And I need to update where I need to call the function something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MakeMusicClass.shared.setup(Selection: "Question11")
    MakeMusicClass.shared.play() {

    MakeMusicClass.shared.setup(Selection: "Answer11")
    MakeMusicClass.shared.play()
}
```

I have spent ages trying to get my head around this, but I am struggling. My code here is clearly not working as there is something fundamental that I am missing. I have tried passing void and parameters, but I don't understand what parameters should be passed.  The closest I have come is using the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying within the makemusic class trigger the next audio file, but I don't know that this is ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet will be in your `MakeMusicClass` taking an `Array` as an initialiser e.g. a question and and answer, and then use `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` to trigger the next file, which I think is what you are trying to get at (and very close ^________*).

For example:

```
class AudioLooper: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var debugView = true

var audioLoopPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

var audioFileIndex: Int = 0

var audioFileArray: [String] = []

//-------------------------------------------------
//MARK: Audio Player Initialisation & Functionality
//-------------------------------------------------

/// Function To Initialise The Audio Loop Player
///
/// - Parameter audioFiles: [String] - The Array Of Audio Files To Play
func initAudioPlayerWith(audioFiles: [String]) {

    audioFileArray = audioFiles

    if debugView { print("Audio Files To Play In Sequence == \(audioFileArray)") }

}

/// Function To Play An Array Of Audio Files
///
/// - Parameter index: (Int) - The Current Index Of The Audio Sequence
func playAudioLoopAt(index: Int) {

    let currentAudioFile = "\(audioFileArray[audioFileIndex])"

    if let audioFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentAudioFile, ofType: "mp3"){

        do {
            let audioFileUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: audioFilePath)

            // Set An Instance Of AVAudioSession Which Allows Playback Even When Device Is Muted
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            audioLoopPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileUrl)
            audioLoopPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioLoopPlayer.delegate = self
            audioLoopPlayer.play()
            if debugView { print("Playing \(currentAudioFile) ") }
            audioFileIndex += 1

        } catch {
            print("Error Playing Audio")
        }

    } else {

        print("Error Finding File: \(currentAudioFile)")
    }

}

/// Function To Continue The Audio Sequence
@objc func continueAudioLoop(){

    playAudioLoopAt(index: audioFileIndex)
}

/// Function To Stop The Audio Looop Player
func stopAudioPlayer() {

    if audioLoopPlayer != nil {
        audioFileIndex=0
        audioLoopPlayer.stop()
        audioLoopPlayer = nil
    }

}

//-----------------------------
//MARK: AVAudio Player Delegate
//-----------------------------

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {

    if audioFileIndex < audioFileArray.count {

        self.perform(#selector(continueAudioLoop), with: self, afterDelay: 0.5)

    }else{

        audioFileIndex=0

      }
  }
}
```

In my example you simply init like so:

```
    audioLooper = AudioLooper()
    audioLooper?.initAudioPlayerWith(audioFiles: ["question", "answer"])
    audioLooper?.playAudioLoopAt(index: 0)
```

Where audioLooper is declared like so : `var audioLooper:AudioLooper?`

Clearly my example is not a Singleton, but it should give you an idea of how you can adjust your `MakeMusicClass` to make it fit...

You can also add a `Delegate` Method like so to inform the `ViewController` the audio has finished or perform some other task like update the next question etc e.g:

```
@objc protocol AudioLooperDelegate {

   @objc optional func update()
}
```

Then in your `ViewController`:

```
var delegate: AudioLooperDelegate?
```

And in the `AudioLooper` Class you can then add the delegate method where needed e.g:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {

if audioFileIndex < audioFileArray.count {

    self.perform(#selector(continueAudioLoop), with: self, afterDelay: 0.5)

}else{

    audioFileIndex=0
   delegate?.updateUI!()

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Ah the delegate method you added did the trick for me !! I was struggling with the functionality with the array as I need to update the UI after the first sound was played, now working beautifully for me, thanks!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :) please mark as a correct answer if you can :)